CSRF Token in Angular 17 using django
I am using django for backend and for POST/GET request I am using this function which is
def player_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        players = Player.objects.all().values() # get all players as Python dictionaries
        player_list = list(players)
        return JsonResponse(player_list, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body) # load JSON data from request
            player = Player(**data) # create a new player instance
            player.full_clean()  # validate the player instance
            player.save() # save the player instance to the database
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Player created successfully.'}, status=201)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid JSON', status=400)
        except ValidationError as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': e.message_dict}, status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid HTTP method', status=405)

if I add @csrf_exempt above my function then it fetch the POST the data in database otherwise my Angular apps gives me 403 error. even I have added in app.module.ts
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'csrftoken',
      headerName: 'X-CSRFToken'
    })
  ],

and my POST fucntion in service is
 postPlayers(player: Player): Observable<any>
 {
    return this.http.post(this.url, player, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }});
 }

I am new so I am not able to figure it out. can anyone help me please?
The data should be store in the database with CSRF token but its not.

step1
Either on your Angular code use the default csrf header name

default csrf header name:  HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN

or
on django's settings.py set the custom name for csrf header:
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'X-CSRFToken'

reference

step2
on django's settings.py
a. Make sure CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY is set to False

Default: False
Whether to use HttpOnly flag on the CSRF cookie. If this is set to True, client-side JavaScript will not be able to access the CSRF cookie.

reference
b. Make sure CSRF_USE_SESSIONS is set to False

Default: False
Whether to store the CSRF token in the user’s session instead of in a cookie.

reference

step3
in Angular 17, on your app.config.ts file
Add withXsrfConfiguration to the provideHttpClient call as follows:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
      withXsrfConfiguration({
        cookieName: 'csrftoken',
        headerName: 'X-CSRFToken',
      }),
    ),
  ]
};

Reference

I tried but still its not working

@AhsanAbdulSalam I have updated the answer, check it out.
If it solves your problem, please accept and upvote the answer so that it can help others too.

well,  I tried it and  your answer didn't help but I have figured it out, unfortunately I am not able to answer it because of some restrictions but only can reply here. it's a bit different. I have made a function in my services to extract the csrf token through "HttpXsrfTokenExtractor" .
